# Redis docker container not recognizing copied files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, dockerfile, devops

I'm trying to run multiple redis containers that use the same Dockerfile to setup their start scripts containing their start parameters like passwords, host binding, log levels, etc.

start-cache.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

redis-server --bind ${CACHE_REDIS_HOST} --save 60 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass ${CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD}
```

The second one looks exactly like that but with tweaked parameters ofc.

My dockerfile utilizing these start scripts looks like this:

```
FROM redis:7.2.1-alpine

COPY ./compose/local/redis/cache/start-cache.sh /start-cache
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-cache
RUN chmod +x /start-cache

COPY ./compose/local/redis/media/start-media.sh /start-media
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-media
RUN chmod +x /start-media
```

My docker compose utilizing the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
  ....
  media-cache:
    container_name: 'media_cache'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/redis/Dockerfile
    command: /start-media
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 6371:6379
    volumes:
      - ./data/mediaRedis:/data
      - ./compose/local/redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: always

  db-cache:
    container_name: 'db_cache'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/redis/Dockerfile
    command: /start-cache
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 6370:6379
    volumes:
      - ./data/dbRedis:/data
      - ./compose/local/redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: always
  ....
```

Don't believe it has any relevancy for my problem but just so it's out of the way, the redis.conf looks like this:

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

My docker compose spits out the following errors concerning my redis containers before having both containers exit with code 0:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 24: /start-media: not found

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 24: /start-cache: not found

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "shebang" line at the very start of your script says it uses `/bin/bash`.  Alpine Linux doesn't normally contain bash or any other GNU tools.

Your script isn't using any shell features that aren't part of the [POSIX shell standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), except for some `set` options that won't matter here.  You can change the script to use plain `/bin/sh`, and remove the `set` options

```bash
#!/bin/sh
exec redis-server \
  --bind ${CACHE_REDIS_HOST} \
  --save 60 1 \
  --loglevel warning \
  --requirepass ${CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD}
```

You can also provide these options directly in the Compose `command:` without using a script, if you'd prefer.  The `redis` image knows how to [inject a `redis-server` command](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/b77450d34ae54354f41970fc44bf840353f59ef4/7.2/debian/docker-entrypoint.sh#L6-L8) if it's not explicitly specified, so you might be able to say

```yaml
services:
  media-cache:
    image: redis:7.2.1-alpine
    command: >
      --bind 0.0.0.0
      --save 60 1
      --loglevel warning
      --requirepass ${CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD}
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 6371:6379
    volumes:
      - ./data/mediaRedis:/data
      - ./compose/local/redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    restart: always
```

With this specific construction, the `$CACHE_REDIS_PASSWORD` would need to be in the host environment or a `.env` file; it is processed before the Compose `environment:` or `env_file:` directives are read.

Comment: Thank you! For whatever reason it still didn't work when I tried using the separate scripts without the `set` options and the plain `/bin/sh`  but it works now by directly implementing the command inside the compose!